# Rotation of cards by Y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, carousel

I have three cards and I want to achieve rotation by Y-axis. It works but
it's buggy when you change rotation. For example if you rotate UP it works but when you click DOWN, rotation goes first time up and after that it goes down. I'm stuck with this, there is a wrong logic in my code but i can't solve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
</div>
<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var cards = $('#carousel > .card'), Next, Previous, revert,  sorted, res
    nexttransforms = [

        {y: '-55%', z: '-50px', scale: 0.8,},
        {y: '55%', z: '-50px', scale: 0.8,},
        {y: 0, z: 0, scale: 1,},
    ];
 revert = Object.keys(nexttransforms).map(function(a){
   return ({[a]:nexttransforms[a]});
});
sorted = revert.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(b)- Object.keys(a))

res = sorted.map(a=> Object.values(a)[0]) // for array

Next = function () {
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      var kartica = cards[i];
          $(kartica).css({
              'transform': 'translateY('+ nexttransforms[i].y +') translateZ(' + nexttransforms[i].z + ') scale(' + nexttransforms[i].scale+')',
          });
    }
        nexttransforms.push(nexttransforms.shift());
};
Previous = function (){
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var kartica = cards[i];
        $(kartica).css({
            'transform': 'translateY('+ res[i].y +') translateZ(' + res[i].z + ') scale(' + res[i].scale+')',
        });
    }
    res.push(res.shift());
};
$('#down').on('click', function(){
    Previous();
});
$('#up').on('click', function(){
    Next();
});
```

```
#carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    opacity: 1;
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    background: black;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
    transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
    background: #add8e6;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    background: #ff7f50;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    background: #7fff00;
}
```

I want to rotate it smoothly UP and DOWN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know from where to start, when you click on next and prev, so you dont need to reorder the items.

so i made sure to only `nexttransforms` as an item list and then reposition them as needed when you click `next` and `prev`

Se the comment to understand

```js
var cards = $('#carousel > .card'), Next, Previous
    nexttransforms = [

        {y: '-55%', z: '-50px', scale: 0.8,},
        {y: '55%', z: '-50px', scale: 0.8,},
        {y: 0, z: 0, scale: 1,},
    ];


Next = function () {
     // start from the right position
     nexttransforms.push(nexttransforms.shift());
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      var kartica = cards[i];
          $(kartica).css({
              'transform': 'translateY('+ nexttransforms[i].y +') translateZ(' + nexttransforms[i].z + ') scale(' + nexttransforms[i].scale+')',
          });
    }

};
Previous = function (){
       // start from the right position
       for (i = 0; i <= cards.length-2; i++) 
        nexttransforms.push(nexttransforms.shift());
   
      for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var x=  nexttransforms[i];
        var kartica = cards[i];
$(kartica).css({'transform': 'translateY('+  x.y +') translateZ(' + x.z + ') scale(' + x.scale+')',
        });
    }
    
};
var first = false;
$('#down').on('click', function(){

    Previous();

});
$('#up').on('click', function(){
    Next();
});
```

```css
#carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    opacity: 1;
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    background: black;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
    transform: translateY(0) translateZ(0);
    background: #add8e6;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(-55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    background: #ff7f50;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(55%) translateZ(-50px) scale(0.8);
    background: #7fff00;
}
```

```html
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
</div>
<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```